# Как в SOAP на PHP добавить к элементу атрибут xsi:nil='true'?

Tags: php, xml, soap

Добрый день!
Работаю с одним сервисом через soap wsdl. Все идет гладко, но при отправке одних данных мне необходимо чтобы каждый параметр в данных, который получает значение NULL передавался через атрибут xsi:nil='true' и как это сделать я не знаю.
Проще говоря мне нужно чтобы запись была такой:

```
<area_common_property xsi:nil="true"/>
```

А она такая:

```
<area_common_property >NULL</area_common_property>
```

Как в SOAP добавить к элементу атрибут xsi:nil='true'?

Comment: Где код формирования запроса?

Comment: У вас уже должно быть прописано namespace в вашем xml. Как?

Answer (score 2):

Можно сделать вот так:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement("<root></root>");
$xml->addChild('area_common_property')->addAttribute("xsi:nil", "true", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
echo $xml->asXml();
```

Вывод:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
   <area_common_property xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
</root>
```

Comment: `<area_common_property nil="true"/>` а хочется `xsi:nil`

Comment: @splash58 дополнил - нужно ещё неймспейс указать

Comment: Скорее всего оно уже прописано, можно просто на него сослаться, чтоб в этом элементе не объявлять